# How to get Aggregation of minimum and maximum elasticsearch using jpql @query

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jpql

I'm using @query to retrieve the elasticsearch data through JPQL.

```
@Query("{\"aggs\":{\"min_price\":{\"min\":{\"field\":\"price\"}}}}")
```

List findByAggregation();

here am trying to retrieve the min value,but i gets the below error

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
```

Failed to execute phase [dfs], all shards failed; shardFailures {[rwtZEaDWQT2ujUgezXSghQ][elastictest][0]: SearchParseException[[elastictest][0]: from[0],size[10]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10,"query_binary":"eyJhZ2dzIjp7Im1pbl9wcmljZSI6eyJtaW4iOnsiZmllbGQiOiJwcmljZSJ9fX19"}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[elastictest] No query registered for [aggs]]; }{[rwtZEaDWQT2ujUgezXSghQ][elastictest][1]: SearchParseException[[elastictest][1]: from[0],size[10]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10,"query_binary":"eyJhZ2dzIjp7Im1pbl9wcmljZSI6eyJtaW4iOnsiZmllbGQiOiJwcmljZSJ9fX19"}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[elastictest] No query registered for [aggs]]; }{[rwtZEaDWQT2ujUgezXSghQ][elastictest][2]: SearchParseException[[elastictest][2]: from[0],size[10]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10,"query_binary":"eyJhZ2dzIjp7Im1pbl9wcmljZSI6eyJtaW4iOnsiZmllbGQiOiJwcmljZSJ9fX19"}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[elastictest] No query registered for [aggs]]; }{[rwtZEaDWQT2ujUgezXSghQ][elastictest][3]: SearchParseException[[elastictest][3]: from[0],size[10]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10,"query_binary":"eyJhZ2dzIjp7Im1pbl9wcmljZSI6eyJtaW4iOnsiZmllbGQiOiJwcmljZSJ9fX19"}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[elastictest] No query registered for [aggs]]; }{[rwtZEaDWQT2ujUgezXSghQ][elastictest][4]: SearchParseException[[elastictest][4]: from[0],size[10]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10,"query_binary":"eyJhZ2dzIjp7Im1pbl9wcmljZSI6eyJtaW4iOnsiZmllbGQiOiJwcmljZSJ9fX19"}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[elastictest] No query registered for [aggs]]; }

how to solve this.????

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40083696/how-can-i-use-a-annotation-to-do-an-aggragation-like-queryvalue-query/40084422#40084422 (hint `@Query` is only for search queries, not aggregations)

Comment: Am new to elasticsearch.. i need to know is there any way to find min using @query through aggregation. and if its no, why?

Comment: Quoting the answer I linked to: "You cannot do it with the @Query annotation whose only purpose is to send a query, not aggregations." Why? Because Spring Data does not support it. The only way is to do as I suggested in the linked answer

Comment: Thanks for your reply and it is useful to me