# How to query distinct records from Elasticsearch via API

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I have the following Elasticsearch get query:

```
GET /...
{
   "size":"0",
   "aggs" : {
      "locations" : {
         "terms" : { "field" : "locationid.keyword" }
      }
   }
}
```

which works on console as it should. But the goal is to have this query programmatic via the Java API. I'm using Spring Boor with ElasticSearchRepository:

```
@Query("{\"size\" : \"0\" , \"aggs\" : {\"locations\" : {\"terms\" : { \"field\" : \"locationid.keyword\" }}}}")
List<Bucket> findDistinctLocationids();
```

So, now my problem is the following Exception:

```
ParsingException[size] query malformed, no start_object after query name
```

The error message is clear but which annotation or is useful for this case instead of @Query? Or is there any other way to retrive distinct records?

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40084422/4604579

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after some hours of try and error i found a solution based on @Vals comment.
First, i set up a search which gives me a SearchResponse:

```
final SearchResponse sr = client.prepareSearch("index").setTypes("type").setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery()).setSearchType(SearchType.DEFAULT).addAggregation(
            AggregationBuilders.terms("field").field("locationid.keyword")).execute().actionGet();
```

From this response i receive a Terms object which holds the results in its Bucktes:

```
final Terms locations = sr.getAggregations().get("field");
for (final Terms.Bucket entry : locations.getBuckets()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    System.out.println(entry.getDocCount());
}
```

with exactly the result as in console is given.

Comment: how would you  do in case you wanna group by (aggregate) and the same time filter (query a filed by value) ?